# Has anyone successfully installed Tensorflow on Raspberry pi zero version 1.3 or can provide a downloadable SD card image of it?

Tags: sd-card, pi-zero, pi-zero-w

I would like to install Tensorflow’s object detection on the Raspberry pi zero. The nearest I have got to complete information is [Pete Warden's blog](https://petewarden.com/2017/08/20/cross-compiling-tensorflow-for-the-raspberry-pi/), however when pip installing the wheel file it just hangs for days.

Also came across [David Salek tutorial](https://github.com/salekd/rpizero_smart_camera3) that sounds perfect! But not sure (what is OpenFaaS?) if it is standalone or requires internet connection, my requirement is that PI must not require internet connection to use Tensorflow.

Just wondering anymore resources or downloadable SD card image with Tensorflow out there?

Comment: Not according to the answer to this question:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/79735/80478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have now successfully installed tensorflow 1.8.0rc0 on the raspberry PI Zero. Here are my steps:

1. Download the Raspberry PI SD card image of Google's AIY vision kit [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/aiyprojects/vision/aiyprojects-2018-01-03.img.xz)
2. Burn the image, i used [Etcher](https://etcher.io/)
3. Download the latest tensorlfow build wheel for the PI zero [here](http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi-zero/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/output-artifacts/)
4. Copy the wheel to the PI zero
5. Open a terminal window to where you copied the wheel file
6. Type the following command, adjust for your wheel file name `sudo pip2 install "tensorflow-1.8.0rc0-cp27-none-any.whl"`